# Expandir con grid 2 columnas

Tags: html, css, grid

Estoy tratando de expandir dos columnas sin poder lograrlo, les coloco el código, todas sus ayudas son bienvenidas.
Este es el codigo del html perdon por no incluirlo previamente.:

```
<section id="home-paragraph-3"><!--Why section does?-->
        <h2>Come and run with us</h2>
        <p id="parrafo">
          We invite you to come relax with us on one of the amazing 
          rivers
          we visit. Check out our trips and let us know which one 
          best 
          suits
          you. We're waiting to hear from you!
        </p>
      </section>


/**contenerdor**/
  #home-paragraph-3{
    display:grid;
    repeat(2,1fr);
    /**grid-template-columns:auto auto;**/
    grid-template-rows: auto auto ;
    grid-gap:2px;
    border:2px solid black;
   }
/**área a expandir, solo queda en una solo columna , es un section y no sé cómo arreglarlo.**/

 section h2{
  grid-column:span 2; /**queda como si fuese una columna**/
  grid-row:1; 
 }
```

Necesito expandir `section h2`, las dos columnas y no sé cómo lograrlo todavía. Las sugerencias serán muy bienvenidas

Comment: No me deja editar tu pregunta, pues, hay otra edición que espera por aprobación. No sé si es un error de tipeo, pero fíjate que section h2{ grid-column:span 2; no esta bien definido.

Comment: Por otra parte, sería bueno adicionar a tu pregunta el código HTML para ver con más detalle.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno no esta claro tu pregunta ya q no dispones tu HTML, pero teniendo idea de lo que dices ahi esta el ejemplo

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border:2px solid black;
}

.wrapper div{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

Sino es lo que buscas, aclara tu pregunta. Mejor si es visualmente